# Make action of on click select box list item laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm developing an admin panel in that shows drivers list 'ld have an select list and having the options "approve","decline".When admin click the approve db field value get changed as '1' and same as click of "decline" db field get changed as '0'.
I've code to change the db value when click ,

```
 public function postApprove($id)
{

    $application = Move::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();
if($application)
{
    $application->approved =1;
    $application->save();

}
}
```

As same as for decline,

```
public function postdecline($id)
{
     $application = Move::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();
if($application)
{
    $application->approved =0;
    $application->save();

}
}
```

Now I'm using two seperate buttons.But How may I achieve this through selectbox list,Can anybody help

[image]

I want the actions **onclick of list item** not on submit.On click of any action like "approve","deny","verification" the **particular action** 'ld made for that **particular user**.

My view code here,

```
   @extends('layouts.blank')
   @section('main_container')
   <div class="main-content">
       <!-- page content -->
    <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="graphs">
                <h3 class="blank1">Drivers List</h3>
                @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <p>{{ $message }}</p>
                    </div>
                    @endif
                 <div class="xs tabls">
    <div class="bs-example4" data-example-id="contextual- table">

    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>

                          <th>Driver name</th>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Phone</th>
                          <th>Total Bookings</th>
                          <th>Completed bookings</th>
                          <th>Cancelled bookings</th>

                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
          @foreach( $users as $user )   
         <tbody>

       <tr class="active"> 

        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>


        <td>{{''}}</td>
        <td>{{''}}</td>
        <td>{{''}}</td>
        <td>

        <select class="form-control" >
        <option value=""></option>
             <option value=""><a href="{{route('toggleApprove',
       ['id'=>$user->id,'isApproved'=>1])}>Approve
            </a></option>
       <option><a href="{{route('toggleApprove',
       ['id'=>$user->id,'isApproved'=>0])}}"> Deny </a> </option>
      </select>
    </td>

    </tr>
      @endforeach
 @endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route:

Route::get('/approve-user/{id}', 'AdminController@approve_user')->name('admin.approve.user');

Your view page like this:

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-flat btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" name="action" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Actions
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
   @if($application->status == 1)
   <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{ route('admin.approve.user',$application->id) }}">UnApprove</a></li>
   @else
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{ route('admin.approve.user',$application->id) }}">Approve</a></li>
   @endif
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">Edit Details</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">View History</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Your controller page like this:

```
public function approve_user()
{
  $id = \Request::segment(3);
  $application = User::find($id);
   if ($application->approved == 1) 
    {
    $application->approved = 0;
    $msg = 'User UnApproved successfully';
    }
    else {
         $application->approved = 1;   
         $msg = 'User Approved successfully';
          }
   $application->save();
   return Redirect::back()->with('message',$msg);
}
```

Comment: Some explanation of how your answer solves the OP's problem would be nice.

Comment: Thanks.Is not it possible with select box.When I use the property "dropown-menu" it not get displayed the list

Comment: Yes this workd for me Thank you                                                                                                               
       <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{ 
       route('admin.approve.user',$application->id) }}">UnApprove</a></li>

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` and `update`,
for a select box you need to get the value through a form

Route:

```
Route:post('post/{id}','Post@toggleApprove')->name('toggleApprove');
```

controller:

```
public function toggleApprove(Request $request,$id) {
   Move::find($id)->update([approved => $request->approved]);
}
```

view:

```
<form action="{{route('toggleApprove')}}" method="POST">
{{csrf_token()}}
<select name="approve">
<option value="1">Approve</option>
<option value="0">Deny</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```